# Error in Commandline Installation of SQL Server 2005 Express SP 3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, command-line, installation

I am facing a strange issue while installing SQL Server Express 2005 on Windows XP SP3 (German OS) machine.

PFB the description:

1. I am performing a silent installation of SQL Server 2005 via a .bat file.
2. The installation command is as following :

   ```
   start /wait Setup.exe /qn INSTANCENAME=<instance name> ADDLOCAL=SQL_Engine SAPWD="strong password>" SECURITYMODE=SQL SQLACCOUNT="NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM" DISABLENETWORKPROTOCOLS=0 TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server \"
   ```
3. The SQLACCOUNT parameter is derived at run-time be checking the language of the OS. In English, it is "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" .In German, it is "NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM"
4. If I provide the above command directly to the command line, then installation is successful. But, if I put the same command in the bat file, then installation fails.
5. The reason for failure mentioned in the log files is that the system is not able to recognize the local system account.
6. In the log files, I checked that when the passed parameter is "NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM" then, SQL logs contain the name of the parameter as "NT-AUTORIT-T\SYSTEM".
   This parameter is invalid and hence, the installation is failing.

[image: Screenshot for different scenarios]

I also tried providing the ".\LocalSystem" as the parameter but, still installation fails.

Please Note:

I faced a similar issue while installing SQL Server 2008 Express on the same machine.
I changed the installation command from "NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM" to "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM", then the issue was solved.